# How to type hint Enum, str using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing

Using Python 3.8 and given these lines:

```
from enum import Enum


class Stuff1(str, Enum):
    A = "A"
    B = "B"
    C = "C"

class Stuff2(int, Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
```

```
def encoder(value: <?>) -> str:
    return value.value.lower()

a = encoder(Stuff1.A) # Will work as expected because Stuff1 is expected as input
b = encoder(Stuff2.B) # Will not work but will not be a warning inside my IDE if <?> is Enum
```

How do you type hint the Enum containing string values in place of <?>, to authorize only `Stuff1` inside encoder parameter ?
I want this value to be an Enum, but I would want this Enum to have string values only. What is the best way to achieve this ?

NB: Yes in Python 3.11 it exists `StrEnum` but I'm under Python 3.8

NB2: I should be able to type my parameter without knowing the values inside the Enum, so `Literal` does not work for me.

I have currently :

```
from enum import Enum

def encoder(value: Enum) -> str:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value.value.lower()
    raise Exception("Non string value as input")

a = encoder(Stuff1.A) # Will work as expected and my IDE will be happy because Stuff1 is expected as input
b = encoder(Stuff2.B) # Will not be a warning inside my IDE as Stuff2 is an Enum too, but contains integers.
```

But I only have the need for string-value Enums, so this code appears like a bit heavy for something simple...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal

class Stuff1(str, Enum):
    A = "A"
    B = "B"
    C = "C"

class Stuff2(int, Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3


def encoder(value: Literal["A","B","C"]) -> str:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value.lower()
    raise Exception("Non string value as input")

a = encoder(Stuff1.A.value)
```

Literal is a good fit here. It does tell your IDE that encoder expects a limited number of possible strings.

However, it modifies your flow a little bit in the sense that you would now have to pass the enum member value rather than the enum member to encoder

Comment: Mmmh I see, but I have multiple Enums with string values and I want to call them generically without knowing the values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use `str` as the type of `value`. `Enum` will not do the trick, even `StrEnum` might not (you would need to change the bases of the enums, and it has different behaviour).

I would also argue that there is very little utility in saying "this function accepts any enum value" -- it looks like you are trying to enforce a coding standard, rather than a static type check, unless you are converting the values back to their enums?

The other option (if you are relying on some shared behaviour other than all values being strings) is to derive your own `StrEnum`-like base (there is a [StrEnum package](https://pypi.org/project/StrEnum/) on PyPI that would help).